# Calculate integral using the residue theorem z=0

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the integral
$\int\limits_{|z|=1}{\frac{{{z}^{3}}{{e}^{\frac{1}{z}}}}{{{({{z}^{2}}+4)}^{2}}}dz}$
$\begin{align}
  & f\left( z \right)=\frac{{{z}^{3}}}{{{({{z}^{2}}+4)}^{2}}}{{e}^{\frac{1}{z}}} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{16}\left( 1-2\frac{{{z}^{2}}}{4}+3\frac{{{z}^{4}}}{{{4}^{2}}}-4\frac{{{z}^{6}}}{{{4}^{3}}}+... \right)\left( {{z}^{3}}+{{z}^{2}}+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4!z}+\frac{1}{5!{{z}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{6!{{z}^{3}}}+... \right) \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{16}\left( \frac{1}{4!}-\frac{2}{4(6!)}+\frac{3}{{4^2}(8!)}-\frac{4}{{{4}^{3}}(10!)}+... \right)\frac{1}{z}+... \\ 
\end{align}$
$\operatorname{Res}\left[ f\left( z \right),z=0 \right]=\frac{1}{16}\left( \frac{1}{4!}-\frac{2}{4(6!)}+\frac{3}{{{4}^{2}}(8!)}-\frac{4}{{{4}^{3}}(10!)}+... \right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n+1}}n}{{{4}^{n+1}}\left( 2n+2 \right)!}}$

I am not sure

Comment: Your result is correct, but it's simpler to compute the sum of the residues at $\pm 2 i$ and $\infty$, where $f(z)$ doesn't have essential singularities.

Comment: $\pm 2i\notin \left\{ |z|\,\,\le 1 \right\}$

Answer (score 1):

As a comment notes, it is easier to do this calculation by thinking on the Riemann Sphere, where the sum of residues must be zero. You can think of this as saying that a loop on the plane extends to one on the sphere, which encloses two bounded regions; the sum of the residues inside one of the regions is the negative sum of the residues in the other. In this case, we have four singularities: the one at $0$, the two at $\pm 2i$, and the residue at $\infty$.

As you noted, $\int f=\operatorname{Res}(f,0)$ so that, by the above observation, $\int f =-(\operatorname{Res}(f,\pm2i) + \operatorname{Res}(f,\infty))$. The residues at $\pm 2i$ are a routine calculation and are found to be $(1/2 \pm i/8)e^{(\mp i/2)}$ respectively, so their sum is $1/4 \sin(1/2) + \cos(1/2)$. The residue at infinity can be calculated by recalling:
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,\infty) = \operatorname{Res}(-z^{-2}
f(1/z),0)$$
So we wish to calculate:
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{-\exp(z)}{z^5(4+1/z^2)^2},0\right)=\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{-\exp(z)}{z(4z^2+1)^2},0\right)$$
and another routine calculation shows this equals $-1$. In conclusion, we have:
$$\int f = 1-\tfrac14\sin(\tfrac12)-\cos(\tfrac12)$$